# Updating a string value with reference to a table - Powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, lookup

I have a script to update a string value in a calibration file but I'm really stuck in basing the update on the following lookup table:

```
Level   PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST   PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_REF
1   85  250
2   90  250
3   95  250
4   100 250
5   105 250
6   110 250
7   115 250
8   120 250
9   125 250
10  130 250
11  135 250
12  140 250
13  145 250
14  150 250
15  155 250
16  160 250
17  165 250
18  170 250
19  175 250
20  180 250
21  185 250
22  190 250
23  195 250
24  200 250
25  205 250
26  205 245
27  205 240
28  205 235
29  205 230
30  205 225
31  205 220
32  205 215
33  205 210
34  205 205
35  205 200
36  205 195
37  205 190
38  205 185
39  205 180
40  205 175
41  205 170
42  205 165
43  205 160
44  205 155
45  205 150
46  205 145
47  205 140
48  205 135
49  205 130
50  205 125
```

For example, if the input file has a line with a PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST value of 85 and a PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST value of 185, I need to look up that value pair in the table and replace the values with the values from 20 levels (table rows) below. If there is no such row, the values from the *last* table rows should be used.

Here's sample code with a *hard-coded* value pair, `(85, 250)` (level `1`), which should be replaced with the values from level `21`, `(185, 250)`, but I need to generalize this approach to work with all value pairs:

```
$file = 'C:\Users\sugas\Desktop\Test\*.cal'
$VTEST = (Get-Content $file | select-string "PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_Test")
$VREF = (Get-Content $file | select-string "PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_REF")

if (($VTEST-imatch 'PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_Test 85') -and ($VREF-imatch 'PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_REF 250')) {
(Get-Content $file).replace($VTEST,'PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_Test 185')| Set-Content $file
(Get-Content $file).replace($VREF,'PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_REF 250') | Set-Content $file
}
```

Comment: PLEASE, do not post pics of code/data/errors. you have it as text, so why force others to squint to read it ...or, worse, to type it in for testing when you can provide it directly.

Comment: What's the skipping levels logic? Always 20 rows? What happens when line 31 is being processed, there isn't row 51.

Comment: @vonPryz  There is but it would be long list. So if you could get me started with the logic of how to apply the logic (Always 20 rows) I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Without showing what your desired output is (what is _skip 20 levels_) and what do you mean by _update two strings_. (update with **WHAT**), I don't think anyone can answer this for you. This is far from clear..

Comment: Let me try the logic question another a way. The list has N rows, right? While `$currentRow+20 <= N`, all is well as we can jump forward. But when `$currentRow+20 > N`, this clearly is not possible. What should happen then?

Comment: @ vonPryz you got the logic correct and after $currentRow+20 > N then we should go with the last row values.

Comment: Anyways, I have written a working code to accomplish the same but I got to write a 300 line program for that, anything better than this is appreciable.

Comment: you code doesnt work. Give an example of output file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the following approach:

- Read the table of values and translate it into a hashtable that maps test-voltage, reference-voltage pairs to their shifted-by-20-entries values, or, if no such entry exists, to the last table entry.
- Find lines in the input files that contain *both* test-voltage and reference-voltage entries:

  - Extract the voltage values from these lines,
  - look them up in the hashtable,
  - and replace the values with their shifted values.

The following solution demonstrates this approach:

```
# Read the table into objects.
# The -replace operation compresses runs of multiple spaces into one space
# each, so that ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimeter ' ' can be used to read the 
# input as a CSV file.
$table =
  (Get-Content -Raw table.txt) -replace '  +', ' ' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' '

# Create a hashtable that maps (test voltage, ref voltage) pairs to their
# new values, 20 items lower in the table, defaulting to the last table entry
# if there is no such item.
$maxNdx = $table.Count - 1
$voltageMap = [ordered] @{}
foreach ($i in 0..$maxNdx) {
  # Determine the index of the table entry with the shifted values.
  $targetIndex = [math]::Min(20 + $i, $maxNdx)
  # Note: We use a *string* key that is the space-separated concatenation 
  #       of the test and ref values (e.g., '85 100'), 
  $voltageMap["$($table[$i].PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST, $table[$i].PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_REF)"] = $table[$targetIndex].PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST, $table[$targetIndex].PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_REF
}

$reTest = '\b(?<label>PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST +)(?<test>\d+)\b'
$reRef  = '\b(?<label>PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_REF +)(?<ref>\d+)\b'

# Loop over all *.cal files
Get-Item *.cal | ForEach-Object {
  # Process each file line by line.
  $modifiedLines = 
    switch -File $_.FullName -Regex {
      # A line that contains both PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST and PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_REF values, in either sequence.
      "$reTest.*$reRef|$reRef.*$reTest" {
        # Using the capture-group values, look up the shifted voltage values.
        $newTest, $newRef = $voltageMap["$($Matches.test, $Matches.ref)"]
        if ($newTest) { # Match in table found, replace voltage values in the line at hand.
          $_ -replace $reTest, "`${label}$newTest" -replace $reRef, "`${label}$newRef"
        } else { # no match in table found, pass line through
          $_ 
        }
      }
      default { $_ } # Pass all other lines through.
    }
  # Echo the modified lines.
  $modifiedLines
  # NOTE: In order to write the modified lines back to the input file,
  #       uncomment the next line.
  # $modifiedLines | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Note: If the `PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST` and `PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_REF` values aren't necessarily on the same line and there's only a *single* value pair per file:

- Use `$content = Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName` inside the `ForEach-Object` script block to read the entire file int a single string
- Prefix the combined regex with `(?s)` to make `.` match newlines too.
- Use `if ($content -match ...)` instead of the `switch` statement.